# If $f(x)$ is differentiable at $x\in [0,1]$ then $f’(x)$ must be bounded in [0,1]. What is the validity of this statement

Tags: calculus

So the statement is given incorrect, but I am having trouble grasping why. If $f’(x)$ is unbounded then there will be points where the derivative won’t even exist. Then how can function be called differentiable?

Comment: You are thinking that $f^{'}(x)$ is continuous, which is not the case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the function

$f(x) = \begin{cases}
  x^{4/3} \sin \frac{1}{x} & x \neq 0 \\
  0 & x = 0
\end{cases}$

Then $f$ is differentiable over all of $\mathbb{R}$. We see that

$f'(x) = \begin{cases}
  \frac{4}{3} x^{1/3} \sin \frac{1}{x} - \frac{1}{x^{2/3}} \cos \frac{1}{x} & x \neq 0 \\
   0 & x = 0
\end{cases}$

We see that $f'$ is unbounded in any neighbourhood of 0. We see that for $x = \frac{1}{\pi (2n + 1)}$, we have $f'(x) = \frac{1}{x^{2/3}} = \frac{(2n + 1)^{2/3}}{\pi^{2/3}}$, which can be arbitrarily large.